# how to eclipse edit source lookup

Tags: eclipse

There's nowhere to select "edit source lookup" for debugging. The only apparent way is to press the button if no source was found, but that button only appears if no source was found. The only instructional is this http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fdebug%2Fref-editsourcelookup.htm

How helpful; all they give is a picture of what the icon looks like, which unfortunately does not even exist on the entire Eclipse IDE. There is no such icon on my eclipse. neither in debug or nor regular view.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Look in the popup context menu for a selected line in the call stack (Debug view in the Debug Perspective).  You should see the menu item "Edit Source Lookup..." there.

Granted, it's not an icon to click on, but a menu item should be just as good.

Answer (score 17):

This is not an answers but I felt a picture would have been more useful!
[image]